# fn.yiiListView.update Cannot read property 'ajaxType' of undefined

Tags: php, yii

im receiving this error. It looks like it's not seeing the id of my clistview, it doesn't even show up on inspect, which is weird.

But I am giving it an id..

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'id'=>'how',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'template'=>'{items} {pager}',
        'pager' => array(
                'class' => 'ext.infiniteScroll.IasPager',
                'rowSelector'=>'.left-pwrapper',
                'listViewId' => 'how',
                'header' => '',
                'loaderText'=>'Loading...',
                'options'=>array('onRenderComplete'=>'js:function () {
                       $.each($(".left-pwrapper"), function(){
                           if(typeof $.fn.yiiListView.settings["\'"+$(this).attr("id")+"\'"]=="undefined")
                              $(this).yiiListView();
                     });
                 }')),
    )); ?>
```

When i go to element inspect, the error shows up here:

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update = function(id, options) {
        var customError,
            settings = $.fn.yiiListView.settings[id];

        if (options && options.error !== undefined) {
            customError = options.error;
            delete options.error;
        }

        options = $.extend({
            type: settings.ajaxType,
            url: $.fn.yiiListView.getUrl(id),
[[[Cannot read property 'ajaxType' of undefined ]]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Cannot read property 'ajaxType' of undefined' while updating Yii gridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559511/cannot-read-property-ajaxtype-of-undefined-while-updating-yii-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48559511/2037924), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26315880/2037924), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25296589/2037924) question, but none of them solved my issue.

What fixed it for me was setting the `ajaxUpdate` option of `yiiListView` in the js call from where I called `update`, as follows:

```javascript
$(element).yiiListView({
    'ajaxUpdate': [
        '1', element
    ]
});

$.fn.yiiListView.update(element, {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below codes and it worked for me. You can give it a try

1. Assign $listView variable to $this->widget

```
<?php $listView = $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(...)); ?>
```

2. Add codes at the end of the view which contains your list view

```
<?php
    $id = $listView->htmlOptions['id'];
    $options = $listView->registerClientScript();
?>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery(function($) {
        jQuery('#<?php echo $id; ?>').yiiListView(<?php echo $options; ?>);
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Sue thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is set 'ajaxUpdate' => true

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'id' => "test",
    'ajaxUpdate' => true,
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'itemView'=>'_testView',
    ));
```

then

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update('test');
```

it works like magic..

Answer (score -2):

When using the function

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update('id');
```

DO NOT USE a #

Incorrect:

```
 $.fn.yiiListView.update('#myList');
```

Correct:

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update('myList');
```