# $.fn.yiiListView.update doesn't update ClistView

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to update my ClistView in Yii 1.1.15, using `$.fn.yiiListView.update`. **I do get it to echo the proper results** back, but it doesn't update the list.

in my JS

```
var ajaxRequest = "lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&lng="+position.coords.longitude;
$.fn.yiiListView.update("store-list", {data:ajaxRequest});
```

in my `actionIndex()`

```
if ($_GET['ajax']==='store-list') {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ........ ";
            $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `store` WHERE `pending`!="1"')->queryScalar();
            //echo $query;
            $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
                                                    'params'=> array(':lat' => $lat, ':lng'=>$lng, ':radius'=>$radius),
                                                    'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                                                    'sort'=>array(
                                                        'attributes'=>array(
                                                             'store', 'state', 'distance',
                                                        ),
                                                    ),
                                                    'pagination'=>false
                                                )
                                            );
            //render page
            $this->renderPartial('_store-list',array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ));
        }
```

in my view, `index.php` i call `_store-list.php` like this

```
<div class="padding-top-20px">
            <?php $this->renderPartial('_store-list', array("dataProvider"=>$dataProvider)); ?>
</div>
```

in my `_store-list.php` i have this

```
<?php 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'id' => 'store-list',
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'itemView'=>'_view',
            'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
            'ajaxUpdate'=>false, //disable ajax sort and pagination
            'loadingCssClass' => '', //remove loading icon
            'sortableAttributes'=>array(
                'dealership' => 'Store',
                'state' => 'State',
                'distance' => 'Distance'
            ),
        )); ?>
```

any idea's why it doesnt update the clistview?

**UDPATED:**

narrowed it down to this. in my `jquery.yiilistview.js` the each loop fails. tried manually setting the ajaxUpdate variable liks this. but still failed. in debug `ajaxUpdate` is still empty. any ideas?

in my JS:

```
 $.fn.yiiListView.update("store-list", {ajaxUpdate:"store-list", data:ajaxRequest});
```

in `jquery.yiilistview.js`:

```
success: function(data,status) {
                console.debug(settings);
                $.each(settings.ajaxUpdate, function(i,v) {
                    $(id).replaceWith($(id,'<div>'+data+'</div>'));
                });
                if(settings.afterAjaxUpdate != undefined)
                    settings.afterAjaxUpdate(id, data);
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it. For some reason had to download Yii 1.1.15 again. something broke i guess.

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update("store-list", { data:ajaxRequest });
```

works fine now.