# 'Cannot read property 'ajaxType' of undefined' while updating Yii gridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, yii

Got following error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajaxType' of undefined"**. Here's my js code

```
 $('document').ready(
    function () {
       $.fn.yiiGridView.update('new-orders');
                });
```

What's interesting, when I'm not calling this function on **document.ready**, but waiting for page to load and calling it from console, everything works fine. but when I'm calling this in code, this error appears, and then when I'm trying to call it from console again, I'm receiving same error. Here's my widget code

```
<?php $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbGridView', array(
                'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
                'ajaxUrl'=>array('/user/profile'),
                'dataProvider'=>$data,
                'id'=>'new-orders',
                'columns'=>array(
                      ....
                )));
```

Comment: I have no idea about this framework but perhaps it's an asset issue. What about trying [``.load()``](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead?

Comment: @Alexander there's no such function in this component

Comment: True, I meant ``$(window).on("load", fn)`` as described in [``.ready()``](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Although, honestly, it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @Alexander , thanks, it worked fine

Comment: You might want to have a closer look at the assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about this framework but perhaps it's an asset issue. You can try using instead:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $.fn.yiiGridView.update('new-orders');
});
```

Don't forget to read [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)'s documentation about the usage of this event and you might want to have a closer look at your assets.